# pyaudio constructor blocks indefinitely

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm running into a problem where the PyAudio() constructor for the python library pyaudio blocks indefinitely, and I can't figure out why.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pyaudio with different releases, and even changed up my python versions (I'm currently using 3.7.1). I've also uninstalled and reinstalled portaudio for fear it was a problem with my Mac.

```
import pyaudio

myAudio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

Instead of this code finishing in a matter of moments, it always blocks indefinitely on the second statement with no discernible explanation. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing libjack solved this issue for me:

`sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-dev`